# PHP how can I optimize this ? many if conditions strpos

Tags: php, magento, optimization, if-statement

I have the following code which checks if some variables contain some specific words.

I'm sure there is a way to really shorter this. I'm a total noob so I can't know for sure how I can optimise this piece of code. Any help would be great..!

```
<?php
if (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) && (strpos($fabriquant,'word') !== false)) {
    echo "Doh";
} elseif (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) && (strpos($fabriquant,'wurd') !== false)) {
    echo "Bam";
} elseif (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) && (strpos($fabriquant,'ward') !== false)) {
    echo "Yes";
} elseif (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) && (strpos($fabriquant,'wierd') !== false)) {
    echo "No";
}
endif;
?>
```

Comment: optimize - performance or readability?

Comment: merge common parts of `if`s into a single one?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds())) {
  $words = array(
    'word' => 'Doh',
    'wurd' => 'Bam',
    'ward' => 'Yes',
    'wierd' => 'No',
  );

  foreach ($words as $word => $message) {
    if (false !== strpos($fabriquant, $word)) {
      echo $message;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A first optimization could be to do nested if statements:

```
if (in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) {
  if(strpos($fabriquant,'wurd') !== false) {
  } elseif ....
}
```

Then you shold test for the most likely condiction as the first check, then the second most likely condition and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

Because all the if blocks have a common component, it would be good to extract it and only test it once.  The other unique points can be checked individually.

```
if ( in_array(1259, $_product->getCategoryIds()) )
{
    if ( strpos($fabriquant,'word') !== false ) {
        echo "Doh";
    } elseif ( strpos($fabriquant,'wurd') !== false ) {
        echo "Bam";
    } elseif ( strpos($fabriquant,'ward') !== false ) {
        echo "Yes";
    } elseif ( strpos($fabriquant,'wierd') !== false ) {
        echo "No";
    }
}
```